# How to access and change value of a cell in multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following dataframe:

```
dic = {'US':{'Traffic':{'new':1415, 'repeat':670}, 'Sales':{'new':67068, 'repeat':105677}},
      'UK': {'Traffic':{'new':230, 'repeat':156}, 'Sales':{'new':4568, 'repeat':10738}}}
d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in dic.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            d1[(k, k2)].update({k1: v2})


df.insert(loc=0, column='Mode', value='Website')
df.insert(loc=1, column=('', 'Symbol'), value=None)
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Metric", level=1)
```

It looks like:
[image]

**How do I access and set the Symbol - Traffic as 'N' and Symbol- Sales as 'USD'?**

I was trying the following:

```
df.loc['Traffic']['Symbol'] = 'N'
```

Comment: `df.loc['Traffic', ('', 'Symbol')] = 'N'`

Comment: Use `df[('', 'Symbol')] = ['N','USD']`